# How to return two widgets in an if - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-widget

I want to return two widgets when one condition is `true`. Something like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
   ...
   if (session.server.autoVenta)
    SizedBox(
     width: size.width * 0.16,
     child: const TextPrimary(
      text: "N° Doc:",
     ),
    ),
   if (session.server.autoVenta)
     SizedBox(
      width: size.width * 0.24,
      child: Text(order.documento),
     ),
  ]
)
```

But using only one `if`.

I've searched on google but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like

```
Row(
  children: [
    if (true) ...[
      Widget(),
      Widget(),
    ],
    Widget(),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can many options to do it :

first, you can use the spread operator inside the `children` in your column to add a `List` of widgets at once :

```
Row(
 children: [
   /* other widgets */
  if (condition) ...[
  YourWidget1(),
  YourWidget2(),
  YourWidget3(),
],
```

you can use for it also a separate `List<Widget>` containing your widgets

or you can use nested `Row` if you don't want the spread operator :

```
 Row(
 children: [
   /* other widgets */
  if (condition) RowWidgets(),
  ),


Widget RowWidgets() {
   return Row(
      children: [
      YourWidget1(),
      YourWidget2(),
      YourWidget3(),
     ],
);}
```